# xpath expression not working in Logic Apps

Tags: xml, xpath, soap, azure-logic-apps

I have the following XML response from a SOAP call

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetContractStatusesResponse xmlns="http://www.proactis.com/xml/xml-ns/">
            <GetContractStatusesResult>
                <Message>Successful</Message>
                <Code>1</Code>
                <InterfaceLanguage>de</InterfaceLanguage>
                <GetContractStatusesData xmlns="http://schemas.proactis.com/p4/contractmanagement/2013/02">
                    <ContractStatus code="DRFT" typeId="3581">Draft</ContractStatus>
                    <ContractStatus code="BAPR" typeId="3582">Being Approved</ContractStatus>
                    <ContractStatus code="RJCT" typeId="3583">Rejected</ContractStatus>
                    <ContractStatus code="CNCL" typeId="3584">Cancelled</ContractStatus>
                    <ContractStatus code="APPR" typeId="3585">Approved</ContractStatus>
                    <ContractStatus code="ACPE" typeId="3586">Activation Pending</ContractStatus>
                    <ContractStatus code="ACTV" typeId="3587">Active</ContractStatus>
                    <ContractStatus code="SUSP" typeId="3588">Suspended</ContractStatus>
                    <ContractStatus code="COMP" typeId="3589">Completed</ContractStatus>
                    <ContractStatus code="NOV" typeId="3783">Novated</ContractStatus>
                    <ContractStatus code="DEF" typeId="3853">In Defects Period</ContractStatus>
                </GetContractStatusesData>
            </GetContractStatusesResult>
        </GetContractStatusesResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am trying to create an xpath reference to retrieve an array of GetContractStatusesData so that i can then loop through each ContractStatus to use the value and also the associated code as well

I have tried various online xpath generators but they dont seem to work properly when imported into Logic Apps, and even to try something more simpler like getting the message value.

These are the ones i have tried by setting a logic app variable

```
xpath(xml(variables('Payload')), '//ContractStatus[1]/@code')
xpath(xml(variables('Payload')), '//ContractStatus[1]/text()[1]')
```

The result I typically get back is `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Microsoft about this and the solution was to use the Compose Action on the XML to JSON using the following, that way JSON is much easer to work with.

`json(xml(<XML content>))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about ALA, but just in terms of xpath expressions

```
//GetContractStatusesData//ContractStatus/text()
```

should get you the text values of all `<ContractStatus>` elements,

```
//GetContractStatusesData//ContractStatus/@code
```

should get you the `code` values and

```
//GetContractStatusesData//ContractStatus/concat(.," ",@code)
```

should get you both.

[You can try this here](http://xpather.com/NWSNeozy).

Comment: OK these don't work either, same result of []

Comment: @Frazer Then I don't know what to say; I wish there was fiddle or a way to try out logic app online.

Comment: the problem (as Thomas Johnson stated) is that there are namespaces involved. This answer assumes XPath2.0 (which Logic Apps doesn't support) but would need to be something like `//*:GetContractStatusesData//*:ContractStatus/concat(.," ",@code)` to work here - `/*:<name>` selects a child element named <name> under any namespace - without it, it will select only elements with the empty (or context-default) namespace

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces come into play.  Try the following:

```
//*[local-name()="GetContractStatusesData"]/*[local-name()="ContractStatus"]/text()
```

As for using concat, for some reason Logic Apps doesn't work with it.

Comment: Logic Apps does work with concat() but it needs to be like this: `concat(//*[local-name()="GetContractStatusesData]//*[local-name()=ContractStatus],' ',//*[local-name()="GetContractStatusesData]//*[local-name()=ContractStatus]/@code)` (I can't recall the attribute also needs the "local-name() query").   

Bear in mind that this would actually concatenate the sequence of all of the ContractStatus text, followed by a space, and then the sequence of all of the @code attributes. I think you would need XSLT to get the equivalent of concat inside a for-each loop under XPath1.0